# Python assignment is not finding the right answer

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm working on a python assignment for a class, and we are required to use the random generator to roll through the assignment(instead of going through the option recursively).

It's a classic problem with a simple answer, but the random selection has to find it by chance. I can't figure out why the output is repeating the same pattern as the functions look solid. Is there an issue that causes the same movement of entities?

EDIT: It outputs infinitely as posted repeating those blocks, but it should stop when all elements are in the 'west' list.

Assignment:
With the Farmer, Wolf, Goat, Cabbage, the Farmer must move all entities to the west side of a river. 
The Wolf, Goat, and Cabbage Cannot stay alone on one side.
The Wolf will eat the Goat, and the Goat will eat they Cabbage if they are alone on one side (east or west).
These restraints are mirrored by the forbidden[] list, and must be checked each time elements change sides of the river.

Code:

```
import random

# The following comments and some changes in the code were provided by Mr. Alexey Pogodin.
# Code has been changed to follow these guidelines.
# All style recommendations below are based on PEP 8 (Style Guide for Python Code)
# http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/
# Python module names should be all-lowercase.
# Global variable names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
# Always surround these binary operators with a single space on either side: assignment, augmented assignment,
# comparisons, Booleans
# whitespace after comma is required

east = ['C', 'F', 'G', 'W']
west = []
forbidden = [['C', 'G', 'W'],['C', 'G'],['G', 'W']]

#Complete the following function so it Prints the objects at East and then the objects at West==========================
def print_contains(east, west):
    print(east)
    print(west)

    return

#Go west: Complete this function according to the instructions on HW4
def go_west(east, west):
    west.append('F')
    east.remove('F')

    isForbidden = 1

    while isForbidden == 1:
        curr = random.choice(east)
        west.append(curr)
        east.remove(curr)

        if (all(x in east for x in forbidden[0]) or
                all(x in east for x in forbidden[1]) or
                all(x in east for x in forbidden[2])):
            isForbidden = 1
            east.append(curr)
            west.remove(curr)
        else:
            isForbidden = 0
            break


    print_contains(east, west)
    print('-------------------------------------\n')
    return east, west




#Go East: Complete this function according to the instructions on HW4   
def go_east(east, west):
    east.append('F')
    west.remove('F')

    isForbidden = 1

    while isForbidden == 1:
        curr = random.choice(west)
        east.append(curr)
        west.remove(curr)

        if (all(x in west for x in forbidden[0]) or
                all(x in west for x in forbidden[1]) or
                all(x in west for x in forbidden[2])):
            isForbidden = 1
            west.append(curr)
            east.remove(curr)
        else:
            isForbidden = 0
            break


    print_contains(east, west)
    print('-------------------------------------\n')    
    return east, west


# Solution: This function returns True if all objects are on the West side otherwise returns False (One line of code)    
def solution():
    if not east:
        return True
    else:
        return False



#DO not change anything in the following lines. Your job is to complete the functions above.
# Main

print_contains(east, west)
print('-------------------------------------')

condition = True
while condition:
    east, west = go_west(east,west)
    if not solution():
        east, west = go_east(east,west)
    else:
        condition = False
```

Output:

```
['C', 'W', 'F', 'G']
[]
-------------------------------------

['W', 'C']
['F', 'G']
-------------------------------------

['W', 'C', 'F', 'G']
[]
-------------------------------------

['W', 'C']
['F', 'G']
-------------------------------------

['W', 'C', 'F', 'G']
[]
-------------------------------------

['W', 'C']
['F', 'G']
-------------------------------------

['W', 'C', 'F', 'G']
[]
-------------------------------------
etc...
```

Comment: What are the `for` loops related to the forbidden list supposed to be doing?

Comment: @Rodolfo I edited to explain the assignment.

Comment: Your code is really not pythonic at all, which makes it a bit confusing to understand.
Python supports booleans, so instead of `0` and `1`, use `False` and `True`. Besides, `1` has a boolean value of `True`, so do not write `while isForbidden == 1`, but just `while isForbidden` (unless, of course, you want to implement different states, but your code does not).
Besides, I have been programming in Python for (only) two years, but never came across the `all` method. I don't think you need it.

Comment: @Rightleg I know, but this is the way the teacher wanted it done. the all method is to test against the forbidden list, but if there's a better way then that's fine.

Comment: `all` is actually pretty useful, once a statement returns `False`, the remaining statement will no longer be evaluated, thus being a lot faster and efficient.

Comment: @EduardDaduya That's what I figured out as well compared to the alternatives. He didn't ask for the all method explicitly, but it was the best way I could find short of recursively sorting through the list/tuple.

Comment: @BleuGamer Yes, a better way would be trying to stay close to English. For example, if you want to know if `elt` is in a `forbidden` list, just write `elt in forbidden`. If you have a `stuff` iterable that must be so that none of its elements are in a `forbidden` list, just write `for x in stuff : x in forbidden`.
This can be argued, but I think it's generally a good idea, in Python, to keep the code close to its meaning.

Comment: I would recommend using the python debugger `pdb` since this is more of a logical problem. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html

Comment: Your all() expressions are wrong.  You just need to check if east/west is in forbidden.  If east in forbidden ...

Comment: @Rightleg I'm a c++ programmer, I just am trying to get through this python intro course in order to go to the rest of the classes. I currently hold a job in systems design, so I'm just trying to do this as painlessly as possible. I'm not a fan of python personally because of the 'english' like programming.

Comment: @EduardDaduya I got your point. Actually, I think I would tend to re-implement this behaviour in my code, so I might gain some efficiency with this method.

Comment: @rrauenza I'm only testing one side of the river at a time, and if it is forbidden it returns the object and then finds another object randomly and repeats. (I have to use random). Is it something else?

Comment: @BleuGamer Well, I don't want to scare you, but you might end up liking Python...

Comment: @Rightleg I've written a lot of python, my uses have been from build scripts to discord bots, and I always gravitate back to either C++ or java.

Comment: @EduardDaduya I've been trying to debug it, and it seems like everything's working properly. That's why I've been confused.

Comment: Let me give this a shot, I'm kinda confused as well.

Comment: @EduardDaduya It acts like it's not randomly selecting an element, but in debugging it is. Yet the output is repeating the same thing over and over, that's why I'm confused.

Comment: What is the `go_west` function supposed to do? Should it move all elements from east to west?

Comment: @maij, to the assignment, the famer moves sides and is supposed to move one element at a time to the same side without causing a combination of entities that conflict with one of the forbidden lists.

Comment: If you had used the debugger properly, or littered your code with print statements, you'd quickly found that you'd only had one item to chose from on the west shore. That's probably also the point where you need to step away from the code and take a short walk to mull over the consequences of that in your head, until the aha! moment.

Comment: @Evert Thank you! And everyone else for taking a look. Stupid mistake, easy fix, will keep in mind for checking all logical restraints to the end of a solution.

Comment: Did it work with the suggested fix? I haven't tried, only looked at the code.

Comment: @Evert I'm not allowed to change the main lists, so I'm trying to see if I can make an if statement to check for only one entity.

Comment: Regarding the use of all, I don't see why you just can't say 'if east in forbidden' - east is an array and forbidden is an array of arrays.  You can test for the existence of an array in an array of arrays ...but you'd need to keep the arrays ordered so they are equivalent -- or use sets.

Comment: "I'm not allowed to change the main lists". Yet your code alters `east` and `west` all the time. You can just add an empty item `''` before you start bottom `while` loop. The only issue that you can't simply check `if not east` to see if the problem was solved.

Comment: By the way, once you got it working, you may also want to take your code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ , as there are a few things which may be written better differently (rrauenza already points out one thing, but there several).

Comment: If you want to live to the letter of the requirements you could do random.choice(east + [None]) and then skip the append/remove code if curr is None.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go east, you *always* ship an item with the farmer. 
After the first journey (going west), there is only one item on the west shore. Thus, the *only* choice to pick to accompany the farmer going east, is whatever you just shipped west. 
So you'll always end up with the same items on the east shore that were there initially: you simply shipped a random item back and forth between the river sides.

One solution would be insert an empty item to ship. It that gets picked randomly, the farmer will just row across on his own. Which is what you want in some cases for the puzzle to be solvable.